# Run app from Flask-Migrate manager

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate, flask-script

I used these lines to start my application:

```
from app import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Using Flask-Migrate, I have this instead:

```
from app import manager
manager.run()
```

`manager.run` does not take the same arguments as `app.run`, how do I define host and port?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`manage.py` replaces running the app with `python app.py`.  It is provided by Flask-Script, not Flask-Migrate which just adds commands to it.  Use the [`runserver`](https://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#runserver) command it supplies to run the dev server.  You can pass the host and port to that command:

```
python manage.py runserver -h localhost -p 8080 -d
```

or you can override the defaults when configuring the manager:

```
from flask_script import Manager, Server
manager = Manager()
manager.add_command('runserver', Server(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True))
```